# NSPredicate state restoration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I create predicate I use some entities

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location IN %@", anno.locationsArray];
//locationArray contains SMLocation Entity
```

Knowing that documentations states:

> If you need a persistent representation of a predicate, create an archive (NSPredicate adopts the NSCoding protocol).

I hoped that there wolud by no problems, but when inside:

`-(UIViewController*)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder`

I call:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"predicate"];
```

I got error:

> [SMLocation initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So it seems that entities used to create predicate, also have to adopt NSCoding protocol. I find it very inconviniet especially implementing to-many relationship which would be troublesome.

I though about preserving Entities using their ManagedObjectID like here(http://aplus.rs/2013/using-state-preservation-with-core-data/) and then recreating predicate, but in my opinion it would by very clumsy way to achive my goal.

**Question**

Is there any clever workaround to restore NSPredicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your limited purposes it seems like you might be able to implement `NSCoding` by coding the `managedObjectID`, you don't really need to save and restore the entire object, just save the ID in encode and return the correct object from `initWithCoder`

Something like:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:[self.managedObjectID URIRepresentation] forKey:@"managedObjectID"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    NSURL*               url = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"managedObjectID"];
    NSManagedObjectID*   oid = [persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:url];
    return [managedObjectContext objectWithId:oid];
}
```

Comment: This solution forces to use shared managedObjectContext(notify me if i'm wrong), but I in my case it seems to be the best choice.

Comment: @kedzia I'm not sure what you're referring to by "shared managedObjectContext"  Certainly it requires you to have some way of accessing the correct managed object context and persistent store coordinator.  Since it's only being used on the main thread (in your case) it doesn't seem like you need multiple contexts or coordinators.